How to type-hint Python function that takes tuple of type constructors?
I can write a function like
async def par_all(fns: tuple[Awaitable[T], Awaitable[U]]) -> tuple[T,U]: ...

But how do I extend this to take tuples of any size, without losing type info? (And ideally not *fns, but I'm fine if it needs to be that.)
Tried something like this but it doesn't quite work, at least not with pyright.
from typing import Awaitable, TypeVarTuple, Unpack

Ts = TypeVarTuple('Ts')

async def par_all(fns: tuple[Awaitable[Unpack[Ts]], ...]) -> tuple[Unpack[Ts]]:
    return await asyncio.gather(*fns)

import asyncio

async def foo() -> int:
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    return 1

async def bar() -> str:
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    return "hello"

async def baz() -> float:
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    return 3.14

async def main():
    result = await par_all((foo(), bar(), baz()))
    print(result)  # (1, "hello", 3.14)
    # The type of result should be tuple[int, str, float], but no luck!

asyncio.run(main())

(And additionally, what's the best way to alternatively take a Iterable[Awaitable[T]] and return a tuple[T]—just with overloads?)

You can't. Doing transformations on TypeVarTuples is not yet possible. I would suggest looking into how zip() does it, but there are existing questions on this topic already IIRC.

Can you say what "it doesn't quite work" means in your case?
